# Calculate compound annual growth rate (CAGR)

Tags: excel, finance

I am trying to set up a spreadsheet that calculates CAGR when `pv`, `fv`, `nper` are given.  I tried using:

```
((fv-pv)^(1/nper))-1
```

but the rate comes out too high. For instance for `pv`=100, `fv`=500, `nper`=10:

```
pv      100
fv      500
nper    10
cagr    0.820564203
```

If I manually calculate the end value, I come up with:

```
0    100.00
1    182.06
2    331.45
3    603.42
4    1,098.56
5    2,000.00
6    3,641.13
7    6,628.91
8    12,068.35
9    21,971.21
10   40,000.00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did 0.820564203 come from?

Comment: ((fv-pv)^(1/nper))-1

Comment: Aha, I see.  I've answered with the correct formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong.  It should be

```
((fv / pv) ^ (1 / nper)) - 1
```

This gives:

```
0   100.00
1   117.46
2   137.97
3   162.07
4   190.37
5   223.61
6   262.65
7   308.52
8   362.39
9   425.67
10  500.00
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.